# How can I update my phone?

Tags: update, htc-8s

I have a problem with my Windows Phone. There is a new software update for my phone and for that I need to have some free space in my phone but I have already 900 MB and I've tried also to reset my phone and it stil doesn't work. It sais: It cannot be opened and I have an error code:800710fe. Do some of you know how I can Update my phone and why it doesn't work?? :s

Comment: Have you tried to do a factory reset? If you don't want that, the only solution seems to be deleting more apps. On other sites, some people say they needed like 700MB and another one said he solved it after he got free space of over 1GB. So either you try to update after every app you delete (or personal stuff like pictures,videos,..) or you make a factory reset.

Comment: sometimes apps like this can help you: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/storage-cleaner/7112c24b-3e72-4dd2-8105-606e9d04b58f They sometimes do clean up a little bit of temporary data that you don't really need.

Comment: What is your phone model?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a lot of HTC-8S phones faced this problem. The error code `800710fe` occurs mainly due to lack of memory in the device. Poor Network connectivity can also be a reason.

As @Southgarden116 said in comments, most users said that the update installed when they had a free space of 700MB or above. However some users have also reported that a free space of 1Gb allowed them to install updates.

So make sure you have atleast 1Gb of space before installing the update.

**Note** : Hard resetting the phone and then updating fixed the problem for many users. Since you have tried that, I am adding it as a note.

**References** :

1. [update error 800710fe - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/update-error-800710fe/4e3d33a2-d231-441c-8eed-7fb2b4ee8c09)
2. [error code 800710fe - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/error-code-800710fe/64e6a766-01ee-4484-a755-3aa17c32c94a)